# How can an incorporeal creature gain a physical form and use equipment?

Tags: dnd-3.5e, incorporeal

I'm playing a level 6 character in a gestalt game and on one side my character is an [unbodied](http://www.dandwiki.com/wiki/SRD:Unbodied_(Race)). Can I gain a physical body somehow? Is there a way I can use the special ability manifestation at will? How can I use equipment?

Comment: Unbodied have 4 racial hit dice, and a Level Adjustment of +4, giving them a minimum ECL of 8. A 6th-level character cannot play one (unless your DM is allowing RHD on one side of the gestalt and LA on the other).

Comment: Savage species also has monster classes. 
There is also the fact that i said that i am playing it. If i am playing it, the GM has already allowed it.

Comment: “You are playing it” does not inherently imply that the DM was aware of the problem, considered it, and decided to allow it as a special case. There are numerous ways that a mistake could have lead to this situation. The comment was solely there just to point it out just in case such a mistake had been made. If none was made, very well; ignore the comment.

Answer (score 4):

## Getting an [unbodied](http://www.d20srd.org/srd/psionic/monsters/unbodied.htm) a body is difficult...

An [unbodied](http://www.d20srd.org/srd/psionic/monsters/unbodied.htm) can't use the special ability manifestation, which is largely exclusive to [ghosts](http://www.d20srd.org/srd/monsters/ghost.htm). An unbodied, therefore, uses magic or like means if it wants a body; the most common method is the 5th-level Sor/Wiz spell [*magic jar*](http://www.d20srd.org/srd/spells/magicJar.htm) [necro] (*PH* 250-1).

### ...But having an unbodied use equipment is easy

There's a feat that allows manipulating specific objects, and a type of object that allows incorporeal creature to manipulate them.

- The monstrous feat **Ghostly Grasp** (*Libris Mortis* 27) grants an incorporeal creature the ability to "wear, wield, and otherwise use" corporeal gear as if the creature weren't incorporeal. Without that feat, the creature can only employ equipment possessing the special ability [*ghost touch*](http://www.d20srd.org/srd/magicItems/magicWeapons.htm#ghostTouchWeapon).
- Items made of **ectoplasm** (*Ghostwalk* 13) possess the special ability *ghost touch*. However, finding someone who can craft such items so the items last indefinitely may be a challenge.

While the unbodied and other [incorporeal](http://www.d20srd.org/srd/typesSubtypes.htm#incorporealSubtype) creatures have Strength as a [nonability](http://www.d20srd.org/srd/specialAbilities.htm#nonabilities), a creature with the feat Ghostly Grasp or trying to use ectoplasmic equipment *can* exert physical force upon specific items. Talk to the DM about how to compute such an incorporeal creature's [carrying capacity](http://www.d20srd.org/srd/carryingCapacity.htm). (I have used without issue the house rule that incorporeal creatures have a carrying capacity as if their Strength scores were 10.)

Comment: I still have 0 str though?

Comment: @Simon Addressed in the edit. It's unfortunate the feat wasn't clearer on that point. I think the designers just really wanted armored, sword-wielding ghosts and didn't really think about how PCs would manage with the same feat. Also, the *Ghostwalk* ghosts are different enough that it didn't matter. As if being incorporeal all the time didn't have enough problems.

Comment: Found rules in Libris Mortis p. 143 that say that incorporeal-cum-corporeal creatures gain a Str equal to permanent Cha, Just thought you might like to know.