# The unbodied in an anti-magic field

Tags: dnd-3.5e, magic, undead, antimagic-field, incorporeal

I am playing an [unbodied](http://www.dandwiki.com/wiki/SRD:Unbodied_(Race)), I had some trouble with the GM about what happens in an [anti-magic field](http://www.d20srd.org/srd/spells/antimagicField.htm). I believe that since there is no comma, and no "and" between "incorporeal" and "undead" in the sentence "Summoned creatures of any type and incorporeal undead wink out if they enter an anti-magic field" It would not affect Undead nor incorporeal but only incorporeal undead while he does not, this is D&D 3.5.

Comment: (This sounds less like a rules dispute and more an effort by the DM to find ways to hamper your character. Based on this question and [this other one](http://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/63909/8610), you probably shouldn't be encountering an *anti-magic field* at character level 6, even in gestalt. Consider discussing your character choice with the DM. Maybe you'd both be better off if you were playing something more conventional?)

Comment: @HeyICanChan It's not that he'll be encountering one from the DM, more likely he's looking to generate one ASAP. An unbodied in an Anti Magic Field (assuming it doesn't wink out) is pretty hard to do anything about.

Comment: @StephenTG While true, it's equally hard for the unbodied to do anything except, well, exist. (I guess such a situation *does* make for a perfect spy, but there are also much easier ways to be a good spy.)

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Later on it says "Elementals, corporeal undead, and outsiders are likewise unaffected unless summoned." This clarifying statement confirms that the usage of "incorporeal undead" as a singular noun. Additionally I wouldn't consider an unbodied as an undead type as it is a psionic type so in looking at the overall concept of an anti magic field, an unbodied would not be affected.

Answer (score 6):

You're right, he's wrong, "incorporeal undead" is a compound noun, not two nouns.

Answer (score 1):

Rules Compendium updated the antimagic rules; incorporeal creatures disappear in AMF. (RC, p.11)

> Summoned creatures of any type disappear if they enter an antimagic area. Incorporeal creatures do the same. These creatures reappear in the same spot once the antimagic effect goes away, unless they were summoned by an effect whose duration has expired—see Spells, below

Additionally, the original RAW does indeed only mention incorporeal versus corporeal undead, but the difference is the incorporeality. That difference could show rules intent that it's the incorporeal nature of the creature that causes its disappearance. In the non-psionic portion of the SRD, AKA the core rulebooks, only undead are incorporeal, so the authors and editors at the time appear to have overlooked that it was possible to have living incorporeal creatures. The DM has a leg to stand on mechanically, and thematically as well.

Interestingly, incorporeality is unmentioned in [Null Psionics Field](http://www.dndsrd.net/psionicPowersGtoP.html#null-psionic-field), even though they kept the phrasing "...*corporeal* undead...", with the emphasis being mine.

[unrelated to question re:unbodied; I'd originally misread unbodied as uncarnate] Psion Uncarnate's 10th ability (Uncarnate) is listed as (Ex), however, so DM adjudication (fiat) might be needed, as Ex abilities continue to function in AMF. If your DM says you're Good To Go, get the ghostly grasp feat (Libris Mortis) if you're planning on doing much in an AMF.[/unrelated]

Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps he's being influenced by other versions of the spell; the 3e version is substantially weaker than the original and for that, you are right.